# Detail in proof for $A\operatorname{adj}(A) = |A| I $

Tags: matrices, determinant

While proving this, this simplification is necessary;

[image]

[image]

In the intervening step, how do the other elements end up as 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property (which can be stated in any of these 2 ways).

> The sum of products of the elements of $i^{th}$ row of $A$ and $j^{th}$ column of $\text{adj}(A)$ = $\begin{cases} |A| & \text{ if } j =i \\0 & \text{ if } j \ne i\end{cases}$

or

> The sum of products of the elements of $i^{th}$ column of $A$ and $j^{th}$ row of $\text{adj}(A)$ = $\begin{cases} |A| & \text{ if } j =i \\0 & \text{ if } j \ne i\end{cases}$

You can verify that.

> Taking $1^{st}$ row of $A$ and $1^{st}$ column of $\text{adj}(A)$,

$\begin{align}a_{11}A_{11} + a_{12}A_{12} + a_{13}A_{13} &= a_{11}(a_{22}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{32}) + a_{12}(a_{23}a_{31} - a_{21}a_{33}) \\& +a_{13}(a_{21}a_{32} - a_{31}a_{22}) = |A|\end{align}$

---

> Taking $1^{st}$ row of $A$ and $2^{nd}$ column of $\text{adj}(A)$,

$\begin{align}a_{11}A_{21} + a_{12}A_{22} + a_{13}A_{23}  & = a_{11}(a_{32}a_{13} - a_{12}a_{33}) + a_{12}(a_{11}a_{33} - a_{13}a_{31}) \\& +a_{13}(a_{31}a_{12} - a_{11}a_{32}) = 0\end{align}$

Comment: This is great, but just for clarification; is there any way to prove it besides testing every combination?

Comment: Yes, but it is tedious to show in general for an $n\times n$ matrix. You have to go with the expanded expression of determinant for an $n\times n$ matrix, consider the matrix multiplication summation formula. That's why many books show that this holds for $3 \times 3$ or $4\times 4$ matrices.